CSS Grid Template
I want to create this template using grid:

I am new to grid I don't know the properties and how to use it wisely to create this template I am worked on flex properties but I am not getting how to achieve this using flex so I am trying this with grid.
I tried searching online about grid and I got some referral using that I modified for my requirement here is the code.


.co-sculpting-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 264px) minmax(0, 369px) minmax(0, 465px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 264px) minmax(0, 264px);
  grid-gap: 24px;
}

.co-sculpting-grid>div {
  background-color: floralwhite;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.item2 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.item3 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.item4 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  max-width: 264px;
}

.item5 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
<div className="co-sculpting-grid">
  <div className="item1"></div>
  <div className="item2"></div>
  <div className="item3"></div>
  <div className="item4"></div>
  <div className="item5"></div>
</div>



Here the item4 is occupying same width as item5 but it should be like 60% from item5 also need to be responsive in all the viewport 3rd column should have same like the attached image.
Thank you.

Please add what you tryed in your question and explain where you are struggling.

You need to add indicative content to the grid-items, in order that we can see where each is meant to sit in the grid you're trying to create. Also, you've posted HTML (thank you), and not JSX (again, thank you!) which means className should be replaced with class since JS isn't being used.

You could try with grid-column and grid-row


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  gap: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.box:nth-child(1), .box:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 3 / 6;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 6 / 8;
}

.box:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 6 / 9;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>




Use grid-column and grid-row to position elements in a grid layout.


.co-sculpting-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  gap: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  background-color: floralwhite;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.item:nth-child(1), .item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
<div class="co-sculpting-grid">
  <div class="item item1"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
  <div class="item item5"></div>
</div>



